# MSBuild Task and passing properties

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

When the MSBuild task is used, is anything inherited from the current context?

What's the difference between the Properties and AdditionalProperties metadata?  The example and description in the docs is exactly the same.

(I'm using MSBuild 4, as with VS2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is found using Google instead of Bing :)  [Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi notes](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,884435b3-037f-4f7a-972f-d6dc9b6326b6.aspx),

> Like I said previously there are two new ways to pass properties in item metadata, `Properties` and `AdditionalProperties`. The difference can be confusing and very problematic if used incorrectly. Admittedly I didn't know the difference until about 6 months ago *(but soon enough to include in my book ☺ )*. The difference is that if you specify properties using the `Properties` metadata then any properties defined using the `Properties` attribute on the MSBuild Task will be **ignored**. In contrast to that if you use the `AdditionalProperties` metadata then both values will be used, with a preference going to the `AdditionalProperties` values.
>
> Now let's take a look at an example to make this clear. ⋯

Answer (score 1):

This link provides more explanation about these:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/07/17/properties-and-additionalproperties-metadata-for-items-used-in-msbuild-task-s.aspx

Comment: That says the same thing as the MSDN page, but with a few more spelling errors.  The explanation is quite incomplete.  The first example shows that properties in the metadata are applied _after_ those on the attribute, since it overrides the Configuration.  But each example uses Properties or AdditionalProperties (for the same purpose) with no indication of how they mix or why you need two different ones.